# Transferring Files SSH SCP Error Message: 'Stdin: is not a tty'

Tags: ssh, osx, scp

I am using a Macbook SSH terminal and generated RSA key pairs and uploaded remote `id_rsa.pub` with approved permissions. I can connect with remote Apache web server. I can create, open, move, modify and on preliminary inspection can manage files on the web server, no problem ... and generate no error messages.

Surprisingly I can not `scp` a folder nor document from my desktop to the remote server. Nor can I `scp` a folder or document from the remote server to my desktop. Each time I receive the error message:

> stdin: is not a tty

The `scp` command to or from the remote web server does not work with either absolute or relative file location references.

My standard syntax looks like this:

From local host:

```
scp -rp ~/Desktop/foldername username@secureremoteserver.com:~/public_html
```

From remote host:

```
scp -rp username@secureremoteserver.com:~/public_html/foldername ~/Desktop/
```

It appears to be an issue with the `stdin: is not a tty` error message.

What's going on?

If this error is preventing the file transfers, how do I resolve the `stdin: is not a tty`?

Comment: Yes I tried full path and every permutation, same error with rsync.

Comment: Server does not recognize my local desktop for these commands ... I assume the 'stdin: is not a tty' error message is definitely at the root of the problem. -- thanks, cb

Comment: please [edit] your post to include that information.

Comment: Please try `scp -v` (verbose mode) and post its output.

Comment: Oops, this one's **old**! My suggestion still applies, though, if you haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: When you first login to `ssh` - as I take it your'e executing `scp` from within the `ssh` session - use `ssh ${opts} -t`. Or even `-tt` if needed.

Answer (score 7):

The reason for this is that one of the login scripts on the target server is using `stty...` to set up terminal characteristics. The command fails when it doesn't have a tty, ie when you connect with `scp`.

The solution is to protect the `stty` so that it runs only when an interactive session is present. There are a number of ways to do this; here are some examples for bash/sh type shells:

Ugly:

```
stty ... >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Works for me:

```
test -n "$PS1" && stty ...
```

Recommended [elsewhere on SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109552/100397):

```
# Check for a bash login shell
case $- in
  *i*) stty ... ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it matters on OSX sshd implementation but on some systems, when you don't have a tty, the implied home directory with ~/ convention, may not expand and you may get some unexpected results. I know it is not a sure thing but please try with full path names, instead of ~/ construct.

Comment: It seems that even providing a full path, the remote server does not recognize the location of the local directory and file and oddly offers a reference to being unable to locate the local directory and file ... giving a url that refers to the 'remote' root. Weird and frustrating.

Comment: Does not seem to work with absolute url. Remote server gives error  essentially unable to locate the local directory and file to copy.

Comment: @user2217265 Could you please add the exact command and error message to your question?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when my .bash_profile tries to load. I added

[ -z "${PS1}" ] && return;

At the top and it fixed it