# "stdin: is not a tty" mails for running scripts as cron jobs

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I have several shell scripts (bash) which are started by cron. Every time a script is executed I get an email saying "stdin: is not a tty". Can someone please tell me how to fix this? All scripts run successfully but these mails are killing my email folder.

I use Debian Wheezy. "/root/.bashrc" is empty. Cron entries are like:

```
/bin/bash --login /root/script.sh > /dev/null
```

Even this script produces the error message:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls
```

Content of .profile:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n
```

Comment: It's something in your script (or in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` since you're telling bash to read it). We can't help you unless you post the script content. If you want to diagnose what it might be, add `set -x` at the top of the script.

Comment: @Gilles: Thx. The scripts are quite long but even calling 'ls' produces the error.

Comment: `stty` and `mesg` are the typical culprits. You can run them with a `2>/dev/null` to quiet them.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: I have commented 'mesg n' out (whatever is does) and it works but this doesn't seems to be the right solution. If I write '2>/dev/null' instead of '>/dev/null' I don't get the "stdin:..." error message but instead the output of the ls command which I also don't want.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say to put 2>/dev/null just on the line that does the `mesg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something in your `.bashrc` is assuming that the shell is running on a terminal. That's perfectly fine: `.bashrc` is supposed to run only in interactive shells, and interactive shells are supposed to run only on terminals.

The problem is that you're systematically including `.bashrc` from `.profile`. That's wrong: you should only include `.bashrc` in interactive shells.

Change your `.profile` to

```
# Bash doesn't load its interactive initialization file if it's invoked as
# a login shell, so do it manually.
case $- in
  *i*) if [ -n "$BASH" ]; then . ~/.bashrc;; fi
esac
```

Move `mesg n` into `.bashrc`: it's a terminal-related command, not a session-related command.

If you have environment variable definitions in your `.bashrc`, move them to `.profile`. The `.profile` file is for things that are executed when your session starts, typically mainly environment variable definitions, used by any application that you'll run during the session. The `.bashrc` file is the configuration file for bash when running interactively, it typically contains terminal setup, alias definitions, shell options and completion settings, and other things related to the interactive use of the shell.

For background, see:

- [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)
- [How to check if a shell is login/interactive/batch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch)
- [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085) (and follow the links)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to start your cron job in a detached `screen`:

`0 0 * * *    cd /path/to/my/job && screen -dmS any-job-name-you-want ./job.sh`

This works because `screen` allocates a tty. I've had to do this before for example with `expect` scripts. It has the added bonus that you can `screen -r any-job-name-you-want` to view and even interact with a running cron job.