# Copying a local file to remote server using SCP

Tags: linux, scripting, scp

I downloaded a fasta file from the web onto my Mac and have it currently saved in: `/Users/sophia_liu/Desktop/uniprot-proteins.fasta`

I used the following command:

```
scp -r /Users/sophia_liu/Desktop/uniprot-proteins.fasta spliu2@merik2-serv01.mcb.usc.edu:~/home/spliu2/blastproteins
```

My goal is to get the uniprot-proteins.fasta file into the remote university server directory that I specified. However, the result that pops up is:

```
stdin: is not a tty
uniprot-proteins.fasta                100%  316KB 481.3KB/s   00:00
```

Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Better, [Transferring Files SSH SCP Error Message: 'Stdin: is not a tty'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70486/100397)

Comment: May I mention that `~/home/spliu2/blastproteins` will most likely become `/home/spliu2/home/spliu2/blastproteins`? I assume you want either the `~`-shortcut for spliu2's home or the absolute path `/home/spliu2`.

Comment: There is no need to specify `~`, a non-absolute path following `:` will be relative to your home directory.